# cv2.imwrite not saving received image to path or any path

Tags: python, opencv

I am receiving data including encoded images and decoding them in my code. but saving the code to the giving path is not working. but reading the picture works fine.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from base64 import b64decode, decodebytes
import pyrebase
import firebase_instance
//file path
path = 'C:/*/*/*/*/*/*/*/StudentImage'
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(firebase_instance.firebaseConfig)
db= firebase.database()
auth = firebase.auth()


#LOgin 
email = input("Enter your email address: ")
password = input("Enter your password: ")



try:
    user = auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password(email, password)
    
    print('successfully signed in')
except:
    print('Invalid cridentials. try again')
    
token = auth.get_account_info(user['idToken'])
uid = token['users'][0]['localId']

students = db.child("studentsDetail").child(uid).child('Engineering').child('Computer Engineering').child('400').get()    
for student in students.each(): 
    #print(student.val())
    print(student.val()['fullname'])
    matNumber = student.val()['matriculation number']
    retrPicture = student.val()['picture']
    jpeg = b64decode(retrPicture)
        
    base64_image_bytes = retrPicture.encode('utf-8')
    decoded_image_data = decodebytes(base64_image_bytes)
    numpyarray = np.frombuffer(decoded_image_data, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(numpyarray, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imwrite(f'{path}/{matNumber}.jpg', image)
```

Comment: Your `path` is not absolute, so it will start with whatever is your current working directory.  If that doesn't have a `StudentImage` subdirectory the write will fail.

Comment: I already created the StudentImage folder Manually but it does not still store it in the folder

Comment: But you don't know what your current working directory is, so you don't know if you put `StudentImage` in the right place.  Set `path` to an absolute path like `'c:\\StudentImage'`.

Comment: I already changed the file path to an absolute path but it's still not working